# SQL Calculating Hourly Sales

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, point-of-sale

I am trying to create a SQL report that shows hourly sales. This is from my POS system.

There's a built in table that has basically all the data I need, I'm just struggling to calculate the sum of a column if they are in the same hour.

Table `vRPTHourlySalesPerformance` (stripped down to only show relevant info):

| dt_when | create_hour_ordinal | c_ticketitem_net_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-07 11:20 | 11 | 16.00 |
| 2022-11-07 12:20 | 11 | 17.00 |
| 2022-11-07 13:20 | 12 | 18.00 |

I'm looking for a way to output the following.

| Hour | Total Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 33.00 |
| 12 | 18.00 |

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
DECLARE @start_of_day   datetime;
DECLARE @now            datetime;

SET @now = getdate();
SET @start_of_day = dbo.dwf_beginofday_for_day(@now);

--Creates Sales by Hour Table
DECLARE @reportable_table AS TABLE (
    Hour                int,
    [Total Sales]       money
)

INSERT INTO @reportable_table
SELECT create_hour_ordinal AS 'Hour', c_ticketitem_net_price AS 'Total Sales'
FROM vRPTHourlySalesPerformance
WHERE dt_when >= @start_of_day AND dt_when < @now
```

Comment: try `GROUP BY create_hour_ordinal` as part of this

Comment: Seriously @HoneyBadger ?  Ther's no need for version shaming.

Comment: @AaronBertrand In my company (and POS system), the beginning of the day is at 4am and the database of the POS has this function built in, so I figured why reinvent the wheel when there's already a function to grab the beginning of the day for me.

Also, the built in reports in my POS system all use this function. So I also used it for consistency across built in and custom reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are after a simple aggregate:

```
insert into @reportable_table([hour], [total Sales])
Select create_hour_ordinal, sum(c_ticketitem_net_price)
from vRPTHourlySalesPerformance
where dt_when >= @start_of_day AND dt_when < @now
group by create_hour_ordinal;
```

Comment: Thanks! That got me what I wanted. I could have sworn I did that. Thanks again! :)